# (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; .. for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' at line 1")

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm trying to insert data into my mysql database, but I always get the error that something is wrong with the parameters, that I'd like to add into my insert statement, I tried all kinds of solutions and the one with the 's', 's' worked, it got inserted into my db.

Has anybody got an idea what can be wrong?

Thanks.

```
try:
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    insert_cmd = "INSERT INTO TBTAB VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    #insert_cmd = "INSERT INTO TBTAB VALUES('s', 's', 's', 's', 's')"
    # insert_cmd = "INSERT INTO TBTAB VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    tpa= ("szilva", "barack", "meggye", "alma", "korte")
    #cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TBTAB (UserName, Email, TextBoxCont, NodeChosen, CurDate) VALUES ('Caal', 'TomErichsen', 'Svanger', '400esd6', 'Nqdwasorway');")
    cursor.execute(insert_cmd.format(tpa))
    conn.commit()
    return render_template('form.html')
except Exception as e:
    return str(e)
```

error:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' at line 1")
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `format` to insert parameters into your query. Try `cursor.execute(insert_cmd, tpa)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the query parameters as a tuple to `cursor.execute()` instead of interpolating them into the query, i.e.:

```
cursor.execute(insert_cmd, tpa)
```

`%s` in the query serves as a placeholder for a single parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works when I render a page, but when I press the submit button (it's in a form) on my page and on that click the string tuple should get insterted into the database, I get internal server error. Do you know why? Thnaks